# Who recruited this many students without informing Bartleyby?

Tags: plot-explanation, accepted

In Accepted (2006), Bartleyby arranged a fake college so perfectly well. But it went wrong and leads to this many recruits at a time.

[image]

Who recruited this many students without informing Bartleyby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's explained at [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accepted)

> Their plan backfires when the website, which **automatically accepts any applicant**, enrolls hundreds of other rejected students.

---

> **Bartleby**: "I told you to make the website look legitimate, not functional."
>
> **Sherman**: "Hey, you wanted to fool your dad and the guy's not an idiot....and also, it was your idea to to put 'Acceptance is just one click away' "
>
> **Bartleby**: "Yeah, yeah, yeah, put it as 'One click away'...you don't make it *clickable*!"